# call one function after completion of an asynchronous function

Tags: angular, callback, observable, subscribe

I have seen calling functions one after another with promises, i have an async function with observable.

```
getHistoryData() {
    this.generatePayload()
    this.historyDataService
      .getHistoryData(this.payload)
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          const responeData: any = data.dataPoints;
          this.timestampArray = responeData.map(e => e.date.slice(5, 10) + ' ' + e.timestamp.slice(0, 5));
          console.log('temp array' + this.temperatureArray)
          this.temperatureArray = responeData.map(e => e.parameter1 / 100);
          this.dateArray = responeData.map(e => e.date);
        },
      )
  }
```

```
other function is :

 updateChartData(){
  console.log('in update chart data')
  console.log('temp values' + this.temperatureArray)
  this.chartData[0].data =  this.temperatureArray
  this.labels = this.timestampArray
}
```

I want to call one after another. How to do it?

Comment: call it within `subscribe()`

Comment: Do you want to call a method after the Observable "completed"? Because every Observable has three notifications: next, error and complete. It notifies you for every state and you can handle it in the observer. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Notification.js~Notification.html

Comment: i want to call the updateChartData function once the assignmnet to this.temperatureArray is complete.

Answer (score 1):

**solution1:** Calling **updateChartData()** within callback of **subscribe**():

```
getHistoryData() {
this.generatePayload()
this.historyDataService
  .getHistoryData(this.payload)
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      updateChartData();         
    },
  )
}
```

**solution2**: Using **switchMap**(), you access to data within switchMap:

```
getHistoryData() {
  this.generatePayload()
  this.historyDataService
    .getHistoryData(this.payload)
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {}
    .switchMap((data) => {
      updateChartData();
    })
  )
```